# Need regex to find text outside the tags ONLY javascript

Tags: javascript, html, regex

Need regex to find text outside any HTML tags
like

```
<tag>Some</tag>Text, you have <tag url="something">Here</tag>
```

Result:

```
"Text, you have "
```

Here, a tag can be any HTML tag, not specified. Regex should ignore tags and text between text and return text which is outside of all tags

Comment: Do you need to find the text **between two tags**?

Comment: What about `<tag><tag>Some</tag>Text, you have <tag url="something">Here</tag> </tag>` ?

Comment: I wouldn't go with regex in this case. There are some libraries for parsing HTML that would probably better fit your needs. Take a look at: http://ejohn.org/blog/pure-javascript-html-parser/

Comment: No outside the tags..Text which is not inside any tag
for <tag><tag>Some</tag>Text, you have <tag url="something">Here</tag> </tag> i should get ""

Comment: @GuruprasadRao I don't think this is a duplicate, because this question here isn't about excluding the tags, but finding a text node outside of any tags.

Comment: @cezar I feel no difference in them! excluding `html` tags from the question I linked and this question have similarities!.. :)

Comment: @GuruprasadRao: please read my question carefully..that solution in that link gives different output

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just remove all the tags.

```js
var s = '<tag>Some</tag>Text, you have <tag url="something">Here</tag>';
alert(s.replace(/<(\w+)\b[^<>]*>[\s\S]*?<\/\1>/g, ''))
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/iO7gL7/1)

Comment: Need little more help..
regex = /<(\w+)\b[^<>]*>[\s\S]*?<\/\1>/g;
x="Hello - <phone full="9087456311"> My Number</phone>9087456300<phone full="">9087456311</phone>";
splittedText = x.split(regex)

Result: 
splittedText = ["RSVP - ", "phone", "9087456300", "phone", ""]

Expected: 
splittedText = ["RSVP - ", "9087456300", ""]

Here, I do not want "phone" as its a tag name..
what i get is regex is correct it matches perfect but if i split it, gives phone(tag name) in that

Answer (score 5):

It is better to do dom parsing than regex for html content parsing

```js
var string = '<tag>Some</tag>Text, you have <tag url="something">Here</tag>';

var tmp = document.createElement('div');
tmp.innerHTML = string;
var lst = [];
for (var i = 0; i < tmp.childNodes.length; i++) {
  if (tmp.childNodes[i].nodeType == Node.TEXT_NODE) {
    lst.push(tmp.childNodes[i].nodeValue);//use trim if needed
  }
}

var text = lst.join('');
snippet.log(text)
```

```html
<!-- Provides the `snippet` object, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/242144/134069 -->
<script src="http://tjcrowder.github.io/simple-snippets-console/snippet.js"></script>
```

Comment: I need a regex or logic with indexOf or something. Not looking for snippet