# Split text which is outside the tags and exclude tags names too

Tags: javascript, regex

```
regex = /<(\w+)\b[^<>]*>[\s\S]*?<\/\1>/g; 

x="Hello - <phone full="9087456311"> My Number</phone>9087456300<phone full="">9087456311</phone>"; 

splittedText = x.split(regex);
```

Result: splittedText = ["RSVP - ", "phone", "9087456300", "phone", ""]

Expected: splittedText = ["RSVP - ", "9087456300", ""]

Here, I do not want "phone" as its a tag name.. what i get is, regex seems correct as it matches perfect(in this case-[" My Number","9087456311"]) but if i split it, gives tag name (in this case-phone) in that

In reference to my previous question:
[Need regex to find text outside the tags ONLY javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31914360/need-regex-to-find-text-outside-the-tags-only-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of split just match and grab from it.

```
[^<>]*(?=<(\w+)\b[^<>]*>[\s\S]*?<\/\1>)
```

See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/uF4oY4/9

```
var re = /[^<>]*(?=<(\w+)\b[^<>]*>[\s\S]*?<\/\1>)/gm; 
var str = 'Hello - <phone full="9087456311"> My Number</phone>9087456300<phone full="">9087456311</phone>';
var m;

while ((m = re.exec(str)) !== null) {
    if (m.index === re.lastIndex) {
        re.lastIndex++;
    }
    // View your result using the m-variable.
    // eg m[0] etc.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There appears to be some problem with the split inserting the back reference then the back reference becoming an empty string. I'm not sure why this happens. Anyways, here is one solution:

```
var code = 'gXop8pdsf';
var replaced = x.replace(regex, code);
var splittedText = replaced.split(code);
splittedText = splittedText.filter(function(value) {
  if (value != '') return true; //filters through array to remove empty strings
});
```